# Checkout different SVN folder using Source Tree to push to WordPress plugin assets folder

Tags: git, svn, wordpress, git-svn, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using SourceTree to push to my SVN WP Plugin directory. I have set that part up successfully.

**The problem is with pushing to the assets directory** as explained in the wp plugin [FAQ](http://wordpress.org/plugins/about/faq/).

SourceTree only shows the trunk as an available remote:

[image]

The WordPress FAQ states to:

> Start by creating an assets/ directory in the root of your SVN checkout. This will be on the same level as tags/ and trunk/, for example.

**I am not sure how to set that part up.** I am familiar with the terminal, so the solution does not need to be SourceTree specific.

I don't know much about SVN, so I am probably just making a silly mistake. Your help is appreciated.